# The Casing & Protective Layer for iPhone 4 is Free, or Is It?

Tags: iphone

We all understand that the way to solve iPhone 4's [antennagate](http://gizmodo.com/5589336/apple-antennagate-and-why-its-time-to-move-on) problem is to use [case and a protective layer](http://www.apple.com/iphone/case-program/). As far as I understand, Steve Jobs said that all these case and protective layer is available for *free*.

However today as I went to an iPhone reseller (I'm located in Malaysia), I was told that I would have to purchase the case and the protective layer – they would not be given for free.

Now I'm not sure what's wrong here – whether it's my understanding of Jobs' word, or if it's how the way the local Apple reseller works. I understand that when Jobs said that these casing would be given for free, it would be free regardless of which country you are in. It certainly doesn't mean that only US stores would give out the case for free, but  every single country in the world which sells iPhone 4 must give it out for free. But the sales representative told me that it's only in the US that the case would be given for free.

So I am confused: is the local Apple reseller running around like ancient Chinese warlords and take no directive command from the HQ?

Comment: +1 for the phrase "running around like ancient Chinese warlords"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The free case program is no longer automatic, and it was never done in-store. You had to download an app to request your free case. (That was their way to make sure only one case was requested per-phone.) I'm also not sure if it was ever valid outside the United States.

To get the free case now, you have to call Apple support and complain about phone signal issues. You also have to ask them directly for a free case.

I have no idea if the same deal applies in Malaysia, but this isn't a case of the store trying to cheat you. They *never* gave away cases in-store.

Comment: It was valid outside the US, I'm in Sweden and I got a free case through the app.

Answer (score 3):

### http://www.apple.com/iphone/case-program/

I've heard apple support will still send free cases if you complain of reception issues. I don't know what the policy is in Malaysia.